# Filter images based on search input of image name

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make my search box, filter through several images on my website. So if I type omniknight into the search box, the rest of the images should darken. What I am trying to do can be viewed on this website: http://dotaedge.com/. I have tried the answer from this question: [Filter images based on search input of image title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983219/filter-images-based-on-search-input-of-image-title) but doesn't work.

Given that I have this markup:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter hero name here" id="search">

<a id="Hero-7" class="hero" hero-id="7" href="#" hero-uri="rattletrap" hero-name="Clockwerk">
        <img class="hero-img-small" src="Dota-Heroes-Small/rattletrap_sb.png">
        <div class="hero-action">
            <img class="hero-img-large" src="Dota-Heroes-Hover/rattletrap_hphover.png">
        </div>
    </a>

<a id="Hero-8" class="hero" hero-id="8" href="#" hero-uri="omniknight" hero-name="Omniknight">
        <img class="hero-img-small" src="Dota-Heroes-Small/omniknight_sb.png">
        <div class="hero-action">
            <img class="hero-img-large" src="Dota-Heroes-Hover/omniknight_hphover.png">
        </div>
    </a>

<a id="Hero-9" class="hero" hero-id="9" href="#" hero-uri="huskar" hero-name="Huskar">
        <img class="hero-img-small" src="Dota-Heroes-Small/huskar_sb.png">
        <div class="hero-action">
            <img class="hero-img-large" src="Dota-Heroes-Hover/huskar_hphover.png">
        </div>
    </a>
```

I am trying to filter through the images using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".hero-name").hide();

$("#search").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text 
    var filter = $(this).val();

    // Loop through the captions div 
   $(".hero").each(function(){

     // If the div item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
     if ($(this).attr('hero-name').search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

     // Show the div item if the phrase matches 
     } else {
     $(this).show();
     }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: It works... check your console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (16:54:53:687 | error, javascript)
    at (anonymous function) (HeroBuilder.php:23:10)

Comment: So that means that you are not properly adding `jQuery` to your webpage. Make sure that you have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>` tags

Comment: Thanks a lot, that got it working to an extent.. Going to fix it up!

Comment: Not a problem. Remember, `jQuery` is essentially Javascript on steroids, but you need to make sure you include the `jQuery` library in your webpage

Comment: I am not sure how to mark your answer as correct, since my original code did work perfectly just this part was missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code works fine. You need to make sure that you are including the `jQuery` library in your webpage.

Be sure to include this in your `<head>` tags. This will make sure that the jQuery library is added, and will allow your functions to work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `indexOf` function to search a substring in a string.
Try this

```
if ($(this).attr('hero-name').indexOf(filter) < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();

     // Show the div item if the phrase matches 
 }
```

Comment: indexOf is actually a Javascript function!

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf to check if `filter` is present in element's `hero-name` attribute

```
// Loop through the captions div 
$(".hero").each(function(){

// If the div item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
if (!$(this).attr('hero-name').indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    $(this).fadeOut();

// Show the div item if the phrase matches 
} else {
    $(this).show();
}
```